# Issue with Javascript to restore scroll position on previous webpage when clicking 'back'

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Currently, on the homepage of [www.Lauramas.com](http://www.Lauramas.com), if you scroll down the homepage, you can click a project, and be routed to that projects page. However, when clicking the back button, to go back to the home page, the user is routed to the very top of the page again, but I'd like to have them go back to the same position and not have to scroll down again.

I've been researching and found this code snippet but can't get it to work, even though no error appears. Just looking for some advice on the best way to get this done. Trying to avoid jquery, because since it's a wp theme I don't think I can put it in the same theme edit section spot as the js which is labelled :

"Custom  content
Enter custom HTML here (ex. JavaScript, Meta Tags, etc.), which will be appended to the  section of your website's markup. If you use an Analytics Service like "Google Analytics", paste your Analytics Code below. Malformed code may break your site."

```
<script>
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', storeScrollPositionInHistoryState)

function storeScrollPositionInHistoryState() {
  // Make sure to add lastScrollPosition to the current state
  // to avoid removing other properties
  const newState = { ...history.state, lastScrollPosition: scrollY }

  // Pass the current location.href since you only want to update
  // the state, not the url
  history.replaceState(newState, '', location.href)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue?